# Cocoa UI Analytics

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plist, analytics

I’d like to track user interaction inside of my OS X application. The goal is incredibly simple to start:

1. Track how many times a specific item is clicked on

I’m using [sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) to enable application updates and am able to send additional information through a delegate method. Read: Sending (client side) and storing (server side) the data isn’t an issue.

My Questions:

1. How can I cleanly attach a “hook” into my system to store an event (like “clicked”)
2. Where do I store the stats on the local machine? (incrementing plist property?)
3. Does such system already exist?

Really appreciate the help. I’m rather new to Cocoa so please ask if you need further clarification on any of the above points.

Thanks again,

Dustin

Comment: Consult Apple's documentation on collection of user data before you proceed too far

Answer (score 1):

> If you set a view as the first responder methods such as -(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent will be fired on the required clicks.

That's true, however it would require you to subclass every single UI element which could get pretty annoying after a while depending upon how many UI elements will require custom analytics tracking.  That said, I can't think of another way to do it - I just thought I would mention the caveat to doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

***1- How can I cleanly attach a “hook” into my system to store an event (like “clicked”)***

As already mentioned, you pretty much just add a little snippet of instrumentation in the responder / call back for the events you are looking for. You also need to be mindful of what you instrument - your goal here is to collect generalised actions, not personally identifiable information or content. For example, if you are building a word processing application, you are looking for:

The user pressed the 'bold' button.

NOT

The user made the text "I am Jack's cold sweat." bold.

***2- Where do I store the stats on the local machine? (incrementing plist property?)***

Anywhere on disk, personally I wouldn't use a plist - but rather a dedicated custom file. The OSX convention for application specific files is: /Users/***username***/Library/Application Support/***application name***

This space is application and user specific, and a great place to store configuration files and all manner of other things that is specific to only your application.

But that is only information from one user, how do you collate this information across many different users? On many different computers?

***3- Does such system already exist?***

Yes. I have been building [UserMetrix](http://usermetrix.com/cpp-analytics) to make it easy to hook into new and existing Cocoa applications via a C or objective-C client. UserMetrix collects usage and error statistics from every user, aggregating them and presenting them as simple web-based reports.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using an analytics service like [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you set a view as the first responder methods such as `-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent` will be fired on the required clicks. All you do, is increment your variable/plist/whatever in that method. Have a look at
[this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/mouseDown%3a).

Answer (score 0):

you can check our DeskAppTrack Analytics. It's a free and good platform for MAC OS X applications.It is all for you and you can get what you want on their web site.

Answer (score 0):

`How can I cleanly attach a “hook” into my system to store an event`

If `an event` is a message sending, that's exactly what I had in mind when I wrote [BCTrackingClass](https://github.com/bertrand-caron/BCTrackingClass) :

> [...] a framework allowing an Application to instrospect its own behaviour,
>   via the logging of its message sending.

It's still fairly in beta version (and I haven't touched it in a while now, although you make me want to get back to it), but do you think that is the kind of solution you are looking for ?

The main advantage of my solution is that the tracking code is fully external to the tracked code (you don't have to manually add a tracking method to every class you would like to use).